# Applying tint to background image

Tags: html, css

I have a following class that has a background image to it, and this is the image I want to apply a tint over:

```
<div class="jumbotron d-flex align-items-center" id="upper-half" style="background-image: url('${mediaInfo.backdrop}')">
  <div class="tint"></div>
</div>
<div class="class2">
  ....
  ....
</div>
```

Classes **jumbotron** and **class2** divide the screen into two parts, both of which are visible simultaneously on the screen.

The problem is, when I apply tint, it applies to the whole screen, even on the class **class2**. Ideally, that should not happen as it is defined inside the h**jumbotron** class.

Here's the CSS:

```
#upper-half {
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.tint {
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? I want the tint to cover only the **jumbotron** class, not anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your `.tint` class is absolute positioned  which is relative to `body` because you have not applied `position:relative` in its parent...

So use `position:relative` in `##upper-half`

```
#upper-half {
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: @PrashantPandey Glad it helped....You can take a reference from here...[**Read this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the `tint` class which is `absolute` and covering whole screen because of its style. Try adding following style to your `#upper-half` and I think it will solve your problem.

```
 #upper-half{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-blend-mode: multiply;
 }
```

Change the width and height to your desired dimension and don't forget to use `position:relative;` or else `tint` will take the dimensions of body.

Hope this helps